# Bit encoding for vector of rational numbers

Tags: memory, encoding, bit

I would like to implement ultra compact storage for structures with rational numbers.

In the book "Theory of Linear and Integer Programming" by Alexander Schrijver, I found the definition of bit sizes (page. 15) of [rational number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_number), vector and matrix:

[image: bit sizes of rational, vector and matrix]

The representation of rational number is clear: single bit for sign and logarithm for  quotient and fraction.

I can't figure out how vector can be encoded only in `n` bits to distinguish between its elements?
For example what if I would like to write vector of two elements:
`524 = 1000001100b`, `42 = 101010b`. How can I use only 2 additional bits to specify when `1000001100` ends and `101010` starts?

The same problem exists with matrix representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, it is not possible just to append the integer representations to each other, and add the information about the merging place, since this would take much more bits than given by the formula in the book, which I don't have access to.
I believe this is a problem from coding theory where I am not an expert. But I found something that might point you to the right direction. In [this post](https://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/puglisi/dct2015/slides4.pdf) an "interpolative code" is described among others. If you apply it to your example (524, 42), you get
f (the number of integers to be encoded, all in the range [1,N] = 2
N = 524
The maximum bit length of the encoded 2 integers is then
f • (2.58 + log (N/f)) = 9,99…, i.e. 10 bits
Thus, **it is possible** to have ultra compact encoding, although one had to spend a lot of time for coding and decoding.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to use only two bits to specify when the quotient end and fraction start. At least you will need as big as the length of the quotient or/and the length of the fraction size.  Another way is to use a fixed number of bits for both quotient and fraction similar with [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754).